# C# multiple button with similar behavior

Tags: c#

I am new to C# and I am following this C# tutorial at the moment. In this tutorial I came across the exercise to develop a calculator.

[A C# .Net Calculator - Design Stage](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/csharp_s2p15.html)

In the solution given in the exercise, each digit button was given a btn*_click method which can be generalized pretty easily.

[image: 1]
<sub>(source: [homeandlearn.co.uk](http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/csharp/images/calculator/buttonCode_Numbers.gif))</sub>

How can we write the code, so that we can generalize these 10 functions? I though it can be done by modifying initializeComponent(), but comment about it says it should not be modified using code editor.

How can this problem be tackled?

Comment: In the future you should copy-paste the code rather than using an image.  If you indent 4 spaces (or a tab) in front of all the code (or click the `{}` button in the editor, which does the same thing), it will automatically format.

Comment: @mellamokb - it is an image linked from the site, which has a gif of the code.

Comment: @afuzzyllama: Ah, k, that makes sense :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The tutorial you posted is using the visual editor in visual studios. By default the designer will generate code with the convention {controlname}_{eventname} you can explicitly assign a different event name in the properties window, and all the buttons *could* share the same event method.

[image]

And then it looks like you *could* refactor this like:

```
private void btn_click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button btn = sender as Button;
    if(btn != null)
       txtDisplay.Text += btn.Text;
}
```

I hope that helps.

Answer (score 9):

You can tie all buttons to the same click event handler, and use `sender` to get the text:

```
private void btnAnyButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Button theButton = sender as Button;
    txtDisplay.Text += theButton.Text;
}
```

Comment: @Nathan has also [posted a good visual](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11143741/116614) on how to link all the buttons to the same event handler, which you may find helpful.

Comment: Answers given by you and @nathan explains it to me. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You could generate these buttons dynamically from the code and assign them some value in the `tag` attribute. From there, you can hook them all up to the same event handler (we're talking about the number buttons, as in 0,1,2,3,4...). In the onClick event handler you would get the `tag` value of the caller and do what you have to do.

Pseudocode:

```
void onClick(Button caller){
  int btnNb = (int) caller.Tag;
  //do what you have to do
}
```

The `tag` attribute is not *necessary* but I find it cleaner than getting the button text and converting to an int.